# Hibernate issues when upgrading from JDBC3 to JDB4

Tags: hibernate, jdbc

Would there be a problem in Hibernate if upgrade from JDB3 to JDB4 is done? 
Does hibernate need to be updated also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand new releases of the JDBC Specification are backwards compatible, therefore if you were using drivers based on JDBC 3.0 Specification you should not be missing anything if you upgrade to 4.0.

Based on this principle I do not see a reason why you would need to migrate to another version of Hibernate if you only upgrade the driver. Although we might conclude that more recent versions of Hibernate probably try to take advantage of the new features in the latest specification, if available.

Even so, I have not encountered any reference to a requirement of driver implementation versions in the Hibernate documentation.

Still any upgrade should not be taken lightly. Perhaps you can upgrade the drivers, run again your test and see if everything works as expected.